# Does the time complexity of an algorithm depend on number of inputs?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

For 100 inputs:

**case 1:**

```
for i in range(100):
         print(i*i)
```

Is it in complexcity O(100) ?

**case 2:**
we have written print() function 100 times manually like

```
print(1*1)
print(2*2)
.
.
.
print(100*100)
```

What is the complexity of this, O(1) or O(100)?

Comment: (You need to indent the code in your first block by four more blanks, or mark it and use "the {}-button" in the post editor. When checking spelling, have a (another) look at the title, too.)

Comment: There doesn't to seem to be anything that varies in that code, if it's *always* going to count to a 100, then it's O(1). If that 100 is what you'd call N, something that varies, then this particular piece of code is O(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, you can use just the iteration count while representing time complexity in  big O notation. But in reality, time complexity depends on both iteration count as well as instructions inside each iteration. It all depends on the use case. If you are calculating time complexity of a complex function just to estimate the approximate cycles, then just considering the iteration count may be good enough but if you are an optimization engineer and you are trying to optimize a module, then you will have to very much take care of instructions within each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that we need **N** operations for executing a printf, we will have in both cases **100N** operations (we omit comparisons in case 1).

Now, to calculate the complexity, we must considerer a reference, something that varies in instances of the program, in order to express the variation of the number of operations according to the variation of this reference. For every instance of your program, you'll have exactly the same behavior, so you'll always have **100N** operations. Because there's no variation between our instances, we can deduce that the complexity is **O(1)**.

Even if that's a correct answer, that's not the only one. You must know that we can also say that the complexity is **O(100)**, or **O(1000)**, or **O(every number that you want)**. Why ? To understand that, we must go back to the definition of O-notation. To be simple, a program is in **O(something)**, if we can find a constant **C** so as for every instance of this program, the number of operations that we execute is lower than **C * that something**. In other words, the number of operations grows proportionally. In our case, since **N** is a constant, we put **C = 100N**, we will then have : number of operations lower than **C * 1**, so it's **O(1)**. But we also have : number of operations lower than **C * 100**, so it's **O(100)**. Number of operations lower than **C * 1000**, so it's **O(1000)**, and so on...

All of that is due to the no variation of the number of operations of our program.